# Does the Dojo palette in the Worklight 5.0.5 plugin have an issue in drag & drop?

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

Dojo widgets drag & drop is not functioning in Worklight 5.0.5 installed on eclipse Indigo.
Is it a version mismatch or is there any other steps that we need to follow?

Comment: This is pretty general, can you provide more details? What version of Dojo, what isn't functioning properly, any error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue on Eclipse Juno, Worklight 5.0.6, Dojo 1.8.3-20130207-IBM when the Design window (drag target) was rendered by Firefox (FF). When I chose IE or Safari (S) I was able to drag and drop from the Dojo Mobile Widgets Palette to the Design window. Not sure if this could be your issue.